# UICollectionViewCells and Inheritance and xibs

Tags: ios, inheritance, uicollectionviewcell

I have what I thought was a simple question but for whatever reason i just cant seem to get my head around it.  So I apologies if its been asked before or im just having a mind blank.

The question is this:

Is there a way of creating the following structure for a UICollectionViewCell:

BaseCollectionViewCell ->  contains a UIView with a layer attached to it and say for example a label (does a few other styling things to the cell like background etc).

then a secondary cell - that inherits from BaseCollectionView.

So if I open up the nib of the secondary cell can i see the UIView and label from the base level?

Many Thanks

Comment: Yes, but you will need to add the UI components from the base cell to the nib for the secondary cell and connect the outlets. The class is inherited, but nibs are not.

Comment: cool, thats Paulw11 - I think the best bet then is to build the ui in code, the UIView that houses the label is going to contain other items for children of the BaseCell.